# Bitcoin Core/Armory installation trouble

Tags: bitcoin

Hello so yesterday I tyried to install Armory, a bitcoin desktop wallet, to house my bitcoins. I am doing this for the sake of undertsanding bitcoins a little more and I do not plan to put large quantities in it as of right now, I am not that stupid. Anyways so I installed armory in ubuntu 16.04 and soon realized that I needed bitcoin core to communicate to the block chain. Fair enough, so I went to youtube.com and rather than doing the simnple PPA methods I found I wanted to compile it myself because I prefer not to truat 3rd parties. I am not Julian Assange but where I can I prefer to not leave dependencies on corporations.

Anyway I followed this YouTube video and I have Armory already installed:

**The YouTube link is in the first imagur link because I am a nub and can only post 2 links, it will be at the bottem of the 3 pictures**

Here is the issue:

When I go to open Armory to play around it first gave me an error saying I needed to go to config to enable rcp. Below is in sequencial order of how that error occured, my cursor is where I clicked:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/FXtpw.jpg

So it was late and I just went to bed. But then today I load into Ubuntu and it does this: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/dvocO.jpg

It has been 30+ minutes and it still has not connected. Any thoughts? I am going to post a picture of the RPC error in a few minutes. If any other logs are needed ask, thanks :)

Comment: alright I will let it alone for a day or some allotement of time and get back. It shouldn't take much more than a day but we will see. Thanks! if and when it is done ill mark this thread solved :p

Comment: Converted my comment to an answer should you wish to eventually mark it as resolved; you can accept the answer to indicate if it is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

What you are encountering is not an error or an installation problem. It's the fact Bitcoin Core needs to download the entire blockchain from beginning to end, and then Armory needs to index it after Bitcoin Core does.

This will take a ***long time*** to sync up.  This is not something you can speed up either.  The Bitcoin blockchain is ***huge*** and Armory needs that fully  synced up Bitcoin Core client for it to work.

Your system needs to sync up Bitcoin Core with the >75GB blockchain before your Armory will move forward.  30 minutes is not enough time to download that, unless you are on 10Gig fiber or something.